# Pegar dados do usuário logado para usar como remetente do email no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

Como posso fazer para mail.php pegar os dados do usuário logado deixando os dados de retemente dinâmicos.
No controller funciona, eu consigo acessar o email  senha do usário logado.
O problema é que em mail.php se eu não descrever o email não funciona.

---

### Controller

```
  use Auth;
  use Mail;

  $email = Auth::user()->email;
  $username = Auth::user()->username;

  $emails = ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"];
  $copias = ["email3@gmail.com"];

  $beautyemail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);

  $beautyemail->send('dashboard.templateemail', [
    'email' => $template, 
    'first_name' => $first_name, 
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'id' => $id, 'cargo' => $cargo, 
    'phone' => $phone, 
    'ramal' => $ramal, 
    'finalizacaodoemail' => $finalizacaodoemail 
  ],  function($m) use ($emails,  $assunto, $copias, $template, $finalizacaodoemail, $email, $username) {    
       $m->to($emails)->subject($assunto)->from($email, $username)->cc($copias);    
  });
```

### Mail.php

```
'username' => "emailremetente@gmail.com",

'password' => "senha123",
```

Comment: Não seria o [Configuring the Sender](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables) descrito na documentação?

Comment: Você utiliza algum Controller para fazer o envio?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer sim, uso, atualizei a pergunta com o código do controller, e de mail.php, o que acontece é que se o meial do usuário logado não for igual ao que está em maisl.php da um erro de autenticação. O que eu queria fazer era no mail.php já tentar pegar email e senha do usuário logado.

Comment: Primeira coisa `mail.php` é o arquivo fixo de configuração dentro da pasta `config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar o e-mail utilizando um remetente dinâmico, você precisa utilizar o helper `config` do Laravel para alterar as configurações em tempo de execução.

[Configuration - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

```
$email = Auth::user()->email;
$username = Auth::user()->username;

$emails = ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"];
$copias = ["email3@gmail.com"];

config()->set([
    'mail.host' => $hostEmail, //Verificar o host do e-mail remetente
    'mail.port' => $hostPort,  //Verificar a porta usada pelo host para envio de e-mail
    'mail.encryption' => $hostEncry, //Verificar encriptação
    'mail.username' => $email, 
    'mail.password' => $password, //Senha do e-mail do remetente descriptografada
    'mail.from' => [ 
        'address' => $email, 
        'name' => $username, 
    ]
]);
(new MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();

$beautyemail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);

$beautyemail->send('dashboard.templateemail', [
    'email' => $template, 
    'first_name' => $first_name, 
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'id' => $id, 'cargo' => $cargo, 
    'phone' => $phone, 
    'ramal' => $ramal, 
    'finalizacaodoemail' => $finalizacaodoemail 
], function($m) use ($emails,  $assunto, $copias, $template, $finalizacaodoemail, $email, $username) {    
       $m->to($emails)->subject($assunto)->from($email, $username)->cc($copias);    
});
```

---

Pode ser que seja necessário limpar o cache do projeto:

`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, acho que ficou melhor pra entender

Comment: Mas porque você quer alterar diretamente o arquivo de configuração (config/mail.php)? Eu pergunto isso porque não entendi o erro que está acontecendo.

Comment: Porque o controller pega sempre o remetente  que está lá no arquivo de configuração

Comment: não consegui encaixar no meu código de forma correta esta parte, da tua sugestão. new MailShipped($params)

Comment: Para utilizar minha sugestão você precisa criar a classe Mailable como eu escrevi. Se quiser ajuda nos podemos iniciar um chat.

Comment: Eu criei a classe, sim podemos!

Comment: Pode me auxiliar? Ainda não consegui resolver este problema.

Comment: Pode me chamar no chat

Comment: chamei agora...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar este pacote https://github.com/ImLiam/laravel-env-set-command
e então usar o `Facade` `Artisan` para executar um comando que altere o valor da variável de ambiente.

```
Artisan::call('php artisan env:set username ' . $user_do_email)
```

Outra solução é alterar o arquivo fisico em sí mas isso seria daria muito trabalho e abriria portas para diversas falhas.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro lembrando que você precisa "incluir as funcionalidades" do `Auth` no inicio do `Controller` (Imagino que esteja fazendo o envio por meio de um).

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

use Auth;

class ExemploController extends Controller
...
```

Então você consegue utilizar qualquer campo referente ao usuário logado:

```
public function enviaEmail()
{
    $data = [
        'email'   => Auth::user()->email, // lembrando que esse campo pode variar dependendo da sua estrutura na tabela
        'subject' => $request->input('subject'),
        'body'    => $request->input('body')
    ];

    Mail::send('emails.suporte', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('smartrahat@gmail.com','Mohammed');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });

    return redirect('algumLugar');
}
```

Comment: da uma olhada atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score -4):

Para pegar o Usuario logado, se você estiver usando [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) você pode usar `Auth::user();`

[Aqui você tem um exemplo do uso do mail no laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables)

Comment: mas isso no mail.php mesmo?

Comment: Eu tentei usar Auth::user(); mas deu erro

Comment: Você esta usando a Autenticação do Laravel? Qual erro?

Comment: Leonardo ao que parece ela precisa alterar os dados de autenticação para ENVIO de email e não definir o `from` que é apenas um atributo do email em sí

Comment: Entendi que era o remetente de acordo com o usuário logado no sistema

Comment: Eu entendi que ela quer mudar o remetente também...